# How to write exitClickHandler function better

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers, show-hide

There are 3 container classes

**Two exit buttons** are viewable **inside** each of their respective **containers**, where they each take you to a different container when clicked on.

```
<div class="container1"></div>
<div class="container2 hide"></div>
<div class="container3 hide"></div>
```

Code I am working on.

How would it be written differently to make it better?

How can this be improved?

https://jsfiddle.net/an23j14r/

```
  function exitClickHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exit")) {
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page1');
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exitPage2")) {
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page2');
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exitPage3")) {
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page3');
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
```

Here are the exit buttons that go to their corresponding CSS classes that they go to in the code.

You would click on a button and it should take you to a specific CSS class/page that it goes to.

There are 3 container classes, when 1 of 2 buttons is clicked on, 2 container classes should be hidden, where 1 of them becomes visible.

```
    <div class="container1">
       <button class="exit exitpPage2" type="button"></button>
       <button class="exit exitpPage3" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="container2 hide">
       <button class="exit" type="button"></button>
       <button class="exit exitpPage3" type="button"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="container3 hide">
       <button class="exit" type="button"></button>
       <button class="exit exitpPage2" type="button"></button></div>
```

Each container/page would be unhidden when a button is clicked on, where the other containers/pages would stay hidden.

When **exit** button attached to `.container1` is clicked on, `.container2` and `.container3` should be hidden.

When **exit** button attached to `.container2` is clicked on, `.container1` and `.container3` should be hidden.

When **exit** button attached to `.container3` is clicked on, `.container2` and `.container1` should be hidden.

**Here is my code example:**

```js
const manageCover = (function makeManageCover() {

  function showCover(playButton) {
    const cover = playButton.parentElement;
    cover.classList.add("active");
  }

  function openCurtain(curtain) {
    curtain.classList.add("slide");
  }

  function coverClickHandler(evt) {
    const cover = evt.currentTarget;
    showCover(cover);
    const curtain = evt.currentTarget.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
    openCurtain(curtain);
  }

  function addCoverHandler(coverSelector, handler) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    cover.addEventListener("click", handler);
  }

  function addClickToButtons(playButtons) {
    playButtons.forEach(function playButtonHandler(playButton) {
      playButton.addEventListener("click", coverClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function init( /*selectors*/ ) {
    //config.containers = document.querySelector(selectors.container);
    // const allContainers = document.querySelector(".container");
    //const playButtons = document.querySelector(selectors.playButton);
    const allPlaybuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    //const allPlaybuttons = document.querySelectorAll(".embed-youtube-play");
    addClickToButtons(allPlaybuttons);
  }


  return {
    addCoverHandler,
    init
  };
}());

const manageUI = (function makeManageUI() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  const players = [];

  function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": allWrappers[index]
      });
    });
  }

  function getWrapper(cover) {
    const index = players.findIndex(
      (player) => player.cover === cover
    );
    return players[index].wrapper;
  }

 function exitClickHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exit")) {
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page1');
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exitPage2")) {
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page2');
    }
    if (e.target.classList.contains("exitPage3")) {
      document.querySelector(".container2").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container1").classList.add("hide");
      document.querySelector(".container3").classList.remove("hide");
      console.log('Page3');
    }
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }

  function addClickToExit(exitButtons) {
    exitButtons.forEach(function addExitButtonHandler(exitButtons) {
      exitButtons.addEventListener("click", exitClickHandler);
    });
  }

  function addExitHandlers(callback) {
    const resetVideo = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    resetVideo.forEach(function resetVideoHandler(video) {
      video.addEventListener("click", callback);
    });
  }

  function init() {
    findPlayers();
    const exitButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".exit");
    addClickToExit(exitButtons);
  }

  return {
    addExitHandlers,
    getWrapper,
    init
  };
}());

const videoPlayer = (function makeVideoPlayer() {

  let player;

  const tag = document.createElement("script");
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
  const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player = event.target;
    player.setVolume(100);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    const player = event.target;
    return player;
  }

  function addPlayer(video, playerOptions) {
    playerOptions.videoId = playerOptions.videoId || video.dataset.id;
    playerOptions.events = playerOptions.events || {};
    playerOptions.events.onReady = onPlayerReady;
    playerOptions.events.onStateChange = onPlayerStateChange;

    const player = new YT.Player(video, playerOptions);
    return player;
  }

  return {
    addPlayer
  };
}());

const managePlayer = (function makeManagePlayer() {

  const playerVars = {
    autoplay: 1,
    controls: 1,
    disablekb: 1,
    fs: 0,
    iv_load_policy: 3
  };

  const defaults = {
    height: 360,
    host: "https://www.youtube-nocookie.com",
    playerVars,
    width: 640
  };

  function show(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hide");
  }

  function combinePlayerOptions(opts1 = {}, opts2 = {}) {
    const combined = Object.assign({}, opts1, opts2);
    Object.keys(opts1).forEach(function checkObjects(prop) {
      if (typeof opts1[prop] === "object") {
        combined[prop] = Object.assign({}, opts1[prop], opts2[prop]);
      }
    });
    return combined;
  }

  function createPlayer(videoWrapper, playerOptions = {}) {
    const video = videoWrapper.querySelector(".video");
    const options = combinePlayerOptions(defaults, playerOptions);
    return videoPlayer.addPlayer(video, options);
  }

  function playerAdder(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    return function addPlayerCallback() {
      initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    };
  }

  function removePlayer(wrapper) {
    wrapper.player.destroy();
    delete wrapper.player;
    console.log("removePlayer");
  }

  function removePlayerHandler(evt) {
    const el = evt.target;
    let container = el.closest(".container");
    let wrappers;
    if (container) { //if multiple players
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".remove .wrap");
    } else { //if single player
      container = el.closest(".remove");
      wrappers = container.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    }
    wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
      if (wrapper.player) {
        removePlayer(wrapper);
      }
    });
  }

  function initPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions) {
    show(wrapper);
    const player = createPlayer(wrapper, playerOptions);
    wrapper.player = player;
  }

  return {
    adder: playerAdder,
    removePlayerHandler
  };
}());

const players = (function coverUIPlayerFacade() {

  function addPlayer(coverSelector, playerOptions) {
    const cover = document.querySelector(coverSelector);
    const wrapper = manageUI.getWrapper(cover);
    const callback = managePlayer.adder(wrapper, playerOptions);
    manageCover.addCoverHandler(coverSelector, callback);
  }

  function init() {
    manageCover.init({
      playButton: ".cover"
    });

    manageUI.init({});
    manageUI.addExitHandlers(managePlayer.removePlayerHandler);
  }

  return {
    add: addPlayer,
    init
  };
}());

players.init();

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  players.add(".playa", {
    playerVars: {
      loop: 1,
      playlist: "djV11Xbc914"
    }
  });
  players.add(".playb", {});
  players.add(".playc", {});
  players.add(".playd", {});
  players.add(".playe", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: ["mnfmQe8Mv1g", "M7lc1UVf-VE",
        "-Xgi_way56U", "CHahce95B1g"
      ]
    }
  });
  players.add(".playf", {});
  players.add(".playg", {});
  players.add(".playh", {});
  players.add(".playi", {});
  players.add(".playj", {
    playerVars: {
      playlist: ["mnfmQe8Mv1g", "M7lc1UVf-VE",
        "-Xgi_way56U", "CHahce95B1g"
      ]
    }
  });
  players.add(".playk", {});
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #302b63;
}

.container2 .container {
  background: teal;
}

.container3 .container {
  background: green;
}

.container1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 255px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain1 {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.ratio-keeper {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 8px 8px;
}

.curtain {
  margin: auto auto 40px;
  max-width: 640px;
  border: 21px solid;
  border-radius: 12px;
  border-color: #000 #101010 #000 #101010;
  position: relative;
}

.embed-youtube iframe,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play,
.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play::before {
  position: absolute;
}

.embed-youtube iframe {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.embed-youtube .embed-youtube-play {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 9px solid blue;
  background: transparent;
  filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px #000000b3);
  z-index: 1;
}

.embed-youtube-play::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 27px solid blue;
  transform: translateX(4px);
}

.embed-youtube-play:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(43, 179, 20, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube-play:focus {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.embed-youtube.active .embed-youtube-play {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  99.9% {
    border-color: red transparent red transparent;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border-color: blue;
  }
}

@keyframes triangle {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  99.9% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  100% {
    border-left-color: blue;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 47px;
  height: 47px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}

.exit::before,
.exit::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: red;
  width: 47px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.exit::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.exit::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exit.exitPage2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 200px;
  left: 0;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.exit.exitPage2::before,
.exit.exitPage2::after {
  background-color: blue;
}

.exit.exitPage3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  bottom: -47.63px;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0px;
  left: 200px;
  border: 5px solid purple;
}

.exit.exitPage3::before,
.exit.exitPage3::after {
  background-color: purple;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <div class="curtain1 remove">
        <div class="ratio-keeper">
            <div class="video-one"></div>
            <div class="wrap embed-youtube ">
                <div class="video embed-youtube  " data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                </div>
                <button class="playa cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="exit exitPage2" type="button"></button>
        <button class="exit exitPage3" type="button"></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container2 hide">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-two"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playb cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-three"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playc cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-four"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playd cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-five"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playe cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-six"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playf cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button"></button>
            <button class="exit exitPage3" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container3 hide">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-seven"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playg cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-eight"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playh cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-nine"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playi cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-ten"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playj cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="curtain remove">
            <div class="ratio-keeper">
                <div class="video-eleven"></div>
                <div class="wrap embed-youtube">
                    <div class="video embed-youtube" data-id="djV11Xbc914">
                    </div>
                    <button class="playk cover embed-youtube-play" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="exit" type="button"></button>
            <button class="exit exitPage2" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `jsfiddle` doesn't match the code example - which one do you want us to help with?

Comment: I don't understand. If you click on the button in `.container1`, you won't be able to click on the rest of the buttons, because they are inside their hidden containers. According to the code, all containers apart from the first also start as hidden.

Comment: Where should the user click to unhide the containers? I would also edit your post, if I were you, and remove everything beneath _Here is my code example:_ because it's just confusing. Just post the code that you want help with.

Comment: Why do you have two exit buttons? What does the other one do?

Comment: Each exit button goes to a different container where it should become visible on the screen, where the other 2 containers should stay hidden.

Comment: Why do all of your comments have 3 upvotes, even the auto generated comments?  It’s not helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is similar to a carousel, you only need two buttons outside each container to control the index of the container that should be visible. The index start at 0 and is then changed ±1 steps depending on which button that is clicked.

`toggleContainer()` checks that the index of the container isn't out of bounce (less than 0 or bigger than the number of containers).

`hideAllContainersBut()` loops through the container "array" and hides every container except the current index.

```js
document.getElementById('prev-button').addEventListener('click', toggleContainers);
document.getElementById('next-button').addEventListener('click', toggleContainers);
let containers = document.querySelectorAll('.container')

var index = 0;

function toggleContainers(event) {
  let indexChange = event.target.dataset.indexChange;

  index = index + Number(indexChange);

  if (index < 0) { index = containers.length - 1; };
  if (index >= containers.length) { index = 0; };

  hideAllContainersBut(index);
}

function hideAllContainersBut(index) {
  for (let i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
    containers[i].hidden = index !== i;
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 15vw;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.container.two {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.container.three {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container one">
    Container 1
  </div>

  <div class="container two" hidden>
    Container 2
  </div>

  <div class="container three" hidden>
    Container 3
  </div>

  <button id="prev-button" data-index-change="-1" type="button">Previous</button>
  <button id="next-button" data-index-change="1"  type="button">Next</button>
</section>
```